# PHP Abstract Method Resolution

Tags: php

I have an abstract class defined as follows:

```
abstract class Abstract Parent extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract { 
    abstract function funcA($post);
    abstract function funcB();

    public function newEntry($post) {  
        $t1 = $this->funcA($post);
        $t2 = $this->funcB();
    }
}
```

The child class defines the two abstract methods, as follows:

```
require_once 'atablemodel.php';

class Child extends AbstractParent {    
    public function funcB() 
    {
        return 'Some Value';
    }

    public function funcA($post) 
    {
        $data = array(
            'v1'    => htmlentities($post['v1'])
        );
        return $data;
    }
}
```

However, when I try this, I get an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /var/www/.../abstractparent.php on line 27
```

which is the line where the abstract parent is calling one of the abstract methods. What I want to have happen is that this line should call the child method, which is defined.

Now, I assume that there is a way to do this, and since I'm a beginner to PHP, I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. Any suggestions as to what I might do to resolve this? If I were to define the two abstract methods as having implementations, and then overriding those methods in all children (that is, not deal with abstract classes at all), how would I ensure that the parent calling one of those methods would call the appropriate child method at execution time?

**EDIT**

In light of the various comments about the issue of combining the static and abstract, I redefined the classes as above, with a new error, also shown above.

Comment: It doesn't make sense for a method to be both abstract and static.

Comment: Except it is - the method is static within the context of the implementing class. The value is always the same, and does not depend on the state of the class. Unless this isn't valid from a compiler point of view....

Comment: Oops... forgot the $ which resulted in the latest error. I was feeling stupid before, now it's worse! Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: @Elie: "In light of the various comments..." - please don't do that. The forum does not exist solely to solve your problems. The question that people have commented on and answered is now gone and their answers rendered meaningless. If you have more questions then create different questions - don't change an existing question to remove the errors you were asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A static method cannot use `$this` to reference itself, as a static function can be utilized without instantiating the class, and therefore `$this` can't be guaranteed to exist.

The `self` keyword can be used to reference methods in the class tree.  You'd want to implement it like this:

```
public static function newEntry($post)      {  
    $t1 = self::funcA($post);
    $t2 = self::funcB();
}
```

However, be aware that there are issues surrounding [Late Static Binding](https://www.php.net/oop5.late-static-bindings) of class structures.  PHP 5.3 can work differently than previous versions for this kind of scope resolution, so be sure to read up on it.  If the parent/child structure doesn't work properly for you, you can always reference a static method by exact classname as well, ie. `Child::funcA`.

Comment: I tried using self:: and got an error regarding using this in abstractparent.php, and using this-> resulted in the error shown above.

Answer (score 1):

To address a method of the current object, you need `$this`:

```
    $t1 = $this->funcA($post);
    $t2 = $this->funcB();
```

calling `funcA()` alone looks for a globally defined function, not a method.

If you want to call the method from outside the object, use

```
$objectname->methodname()
```

Comment: But then I get the error: "Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /var/www/.../abstractparent.php on line 27"

Comment: aaaah, I overlooked the `static`. Then try classname::methodname(), that is the static way of calling a method.

Comment: But I can't call that from the parent, can I? Because then it'll resolve to the parent implementation, which is abstract...

Answer (score 1):

You declared the functions as static, so you can't use them with $this. Static methods can be referenced with self:: or via the classname::

You use $this on an instance of the class on non-static methods.

Comment: I removed all static references for the time being, resulting in the error shown above.